# evil (vi) keybindings for customize-mode

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, evil

A recent convert to Spacemacs and I'm having trouble trying to change the keybindings in customize mode.

From a customize buffer I can change the state with `M-m` `SPC` `evil-evilified-state` and then it works as I expect (navigation, using `SPC` as leader; to be able to insert into the search bar properly you need to go back to emacs mode with `C-z` but I can live with that).

Trying to set this in my config with variants of `(evil-set-initial-state 'custom-mode 'evil,normal,insert,and so on...)` and nothing I've tried thus far is working.

Related: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/6699

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend the recently published [evil collection](https://github.com/jojojames/evil-collection), which solves this problem not only for customize, but also for many of the other modes in emacs. If you just want the customize functionality, [this file](https://github.com/jojojames/evil-collection/blob/master/evil-collection-custom.el) appears to be the relevant one to `customize-mode`, and I think it ticks off your boxes sans the `SPC` leader, but I think that could be rectified with something like:

```
(evil-define-key 'normal custom-mode-map
  (kbd "SPC j") 'widget-forward
  (kbd "SPC k") 'widget-backward)
```

Unfortunately I'm not entirely sure how/if this works into spacemacs as I don't have much experience with it, and I tend to avoid customize mode, but worst comes to worst the aforementioned code could probably be dropped into your `.spacemacs` file along side the file in the evil collection.

As for the issue with getting evil to set the initial state for custom mode, That file appears to capitalize the C in `'Custom-mode`, and although I've never seen a capitalized major mode name in source, [emacs is case sensitive](https://yoo2080.wordpress.com/2013/08/16/differences-between-common-lisp-and-emacs-lisp/).

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Argh, capitalisation! `'Custom-mode` works as I expected now. [evil collection](https://github.com/jojojames/evil-collection) looks really interesting, will be giving it a shot. Thanks for the answer